# Aromaticity of 1,1'-bi(cycloprop-2-en-1-ylidene) and 1,4-dioxine

Tags: electrons, aromatic-compounds, resonance

Are these Anti aromatic/aromatic or non aromatic?

1.

[image: 1,1'-bi(cycloprop-2-en-1-ylidene)]

Here, if we were to consider the resonating structure(s) with charge separation

[image]

One ring is aromatic and other is anti aromatic, and secondly there is not continuous delocalization of pi electrons between those rings {if we don't include no resonating structures with no formal charges, as their contribution would not be equalish to normal form} what category would this go in?

2.

[image: 1,4-dioxine]

Like before, there can be no continuous electron delocalization like stated in previous example , only other ones the diff forms of

[image]

If we consider it to have enough delocalization, it would have 4n electrons and hence antiaromatic {although all the orbitals wont be mixed as 3 on each side twice with oxygen's lone pair being common between all of them}

3. As we can see in pyrene, if we consider central double bond to be non participating, huckle rule works, is there a better (and just by observation by eye) method that we could use for multi ring systems? what is the basic condition for aromaticity besides planar,cyclic,sp2 {nitrogen and oxygen in general change their hybridisation as to make it aromatic with their lone pair(s)}

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: is the second one aromatic or not? and if there is a better way to evaluate aromaticity

Comment: The second one is definitely not aromatic.  It would have 4n electrons if planar; the oxygens would need to be sp2 hybridized to make this molecule planar, meaning there would be a lone pair in a p-orbital each

Comment: i mean anti aromatic or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antiaromaticity is a fictional state with real consequences,  that any molecule will distort to avoid.

In the case of molecule 1, the primary state will be a triplet (unpaired pi-electrons), with the central bond lengthening to decrease the pairing of the pi-electrons.  This will lead to 3 electrons in each pi-system, and hence preventing antiaromaticity, because there are no longer 4n electrons in the rings.  A fictional molecule, with the constituency shown for molecule 1 that is in a singlet state would be antiaromatic.

In the case of molecule 2, the molecule will distort itself to make the at least one of the oxygens non-coplanaer with the pi-system, and no longer being co-planar, the system will not be antiaormatic.  A fictional molecule with the constituency shown for molecule 2 that is co-planar, would be antiaromatic.

It is unclear what you are asking about for pyrene.

Comment: ok, understood, would the same happen ![](https://i.gyazo.com/81dd8367e76467c1822d748ab67b464e.png) here?

Comment: Yes, and the net effect is that the 2-proton in 2-H pyran is basically undeprotonateable.

Comment: Wouldn’t molecule 1 also distort so that the two rings are perpendicular to each other?

Comment: @lighthart so the 2-"proton" in 2H-pyran could in fact be hydridic! In the case of 4H-pyran, which is better known, the CH2 hydrogen does in fact transfer as a hydride ion when it [dispropotionates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyran).