# Is a compound aromatic if it also has anti-aromatic rings?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromaticity

Is 5,6,11,12-tetradehydrodibenzo[*a*,*e*][8]annulene aromatic?

[image: 5,6,11,12-tetradehydrodibenzo[a,e][8]annulene]

If I use Hückel's rule for the whole molecule, I get the answer as anti-aromatic. But the compound has two benzene rings which are individually aromatic.

Comment: I'd go as far as to say there is no such thing as aromatic compounds. Sure, people say it all the time, and we even have a tag to that effect; so what? This is just a shorthand for _"compounds with aromatic rings"_. Aromaticity is a property of one ring, not of the whole compound. A molecule, as you know, may be arbitrarily complicated. It may involve some anti-aromatic rings together with some aromatic ones. Then you'll be compelled to consider such compound both aromatic and anti-aromatic at the same time, which does not feel well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**The molecule actually optimizes to a planar, delocalized $\pi$ system**

Using B3LYP/6-31G(d) optimizations, we see that the molecule optimizes to become planar. (The initial configuration was intentionally bent.)

[image]

Moreover, if I plot the HOMO, it's highly delocalized:

[image]

Similarly, the LUMO is also delocalized across the entire molecule:

[image]

Consequently, I don't see any indication that the "side" benzene rings are localized from the cycloocta-1,5-diyne ring. The bond lengths are in fairly good agreement with the crystal structure:

[image]

Here's the [crystal structure](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00836a041) from [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1975**, 97 (3), 658–659](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00836a041). Note there is a profound triple bond character, but the bridging bonds (1.44 Å) are somewhere between a typical aromatic bond length (1.40 Å) and a full single bond (~1.54 Å).

[image]

Comment: I will admit my initial intuition was that the central ring was non-planar, but figured "why not run a calculation and see?"

Comment: That is bloody weird.  Glad you ran the calc.  Would you add HOMO/LUMO +/- 3 energies to your post?

Comment: Guys, guys, that's how stabilisation via anellation with aromatic rings works. Benzene rings are destabilised, but central more stable. Cyclooctadienediyn most probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @Mithoron - yes, exactly. That's why I wanted to add a better answer for this one.

Comment: @Mithoron Cyclooctadienediyn could exist (at least in silico) and I would like to see the contributions to the stabilization. Dissected into destabilization of benzenes by geometric deformation and also some Huckel-like diagram. Could be a nice paper in J. Chem. Education ;)

Comment: Could the triple bonds have something to do with it?  They favor a linear bonding geometry and thus tend to make the planar structure more "rigid".  Does anyone know what happens if we put hydrogens on C-5, 6, 11, 12 so there aren't the triple bonds?

Comment: @OscarLanzi - that seems like a separate question.

Comment: @Geoff it turns out that breaking the nonconjugated pi bond by adding those hydrogens does destroy the planarity of the central ring.  See [here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Dibenzo_a_e_cyclooctene#section=3D-Conformer).