# Why are non-aromatic rings more stable than anti-aromatic ones?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is there any non-quantum explanation to the greater stability of non aromatic compounds as compared to  anti-aromatic compounds?

Comment: Why are you specifically looking for a "non-quantum" explanation? Perhaps I don't know what you mean by that exactly, but molecular bonds fall into the realm of quantum mechanics. Any explanation that ignores this is automatically wrong

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/45040/why-cant-antiaromatic-compounds-just-escape-planarity-and-become-non-aromatic-t